# How to act in Mosque in Friday Prayer?

Tags: salat, wudu, jamaat, jumuah

I begin praying in Mosque next Friday (InshaAllah).
I never did a prayer in a Mosque (except when i was very young i think) and i need some tips how i should act to not look like a lost person...

Can anyone tell me by steps what to do since entering the Mosque.How the prayer is done?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome back! Watch a few videos to familiarize yourself with the prayer (such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1oF8DG4BDg)) and with the washing process to purify oneself for prayer.

- When you enter the masjid, keep your shoes aside in the racks provided for that purpose and head over to the prayer area.
- If there is time before the sermon or before the prayer starts, offer two units of prayer as a greeting.
- Sit down and wait until the sermon or prayer begins.
- Try to listen attentively as much as you can and don't talk to anyone during the sermon.
- When the sermon finishes, it is time for prayer. Stand up and form rows along with everyone else.
- Offer the prayer, and after you say the salam to your right and left, the prayer is over. You are free at this point to leave.
- At any point, make sure not to walk in front of anyone who is praying. If they have a barrier between them and you, it's OK to walk across on the other side of the barrier.
- Ask the *imam* or someone there who has knowledge of activities in the masjid whether there are any study circles you can join to learn the prayer, learn what is recited in the prayer, and learn Qur'an.

May Allah SWT guide you on this journey!

Comment: Jazaka allho rayran. Still have few points that i want you to clarify to me. If i have something with me like a school bag where i can place it?Is there a place in every masjid always to do wudu and how to wipe off water from your face and hands after finishing the wudu? Is there something specially placed there for that purpose? and what are exactly the differences(what to do and what to say) in praying in jamaa compared to praying alone? :)

Comment: @user3098 you could either keep your back somewhere near you or at the place you left your shoes at. At least the bag shouldn't disturb other people while praying. Each mosque is different and therefore you could find towels and a bathroom (a place to perform wudu) in some of them or maybe find a place to perform wudu, but nothing to wipe off the water etc.

Answer (score 3):

**This is answer of your comment :**

Yes in some Mosque there is a setup to keep your bag or jacket but in some Mosque there is not on that occasions I keep my bag or jacket beside back wall or side wall (not at the front wall case it hard to get after prayer). and most of Mosque I said prayer there is no place to wipe water of your face and hand so it is okay to have a handkerchief with you.

At Friday prayer follow thing has done

- First Iman gave speech about any topic it. It usually start about half hour before jamat.
- Then Iman give you time to offer first 4 units of suna or in same Mosque they don't. If they don't give you time to offer 4 units suna then you have to do it in speech (It depend on Iman so you can confirm it from anyone about that).
- After that Imam will give you **khutbah it is compulsory to lesson to it in Friday prayer** and you don't have permission to talk to anyone when imam is saying khutbah.
- when he will be finished the you for lines and start praying in jamat.

**How prayer is done in jamat:**

prayer in jamat is lot like prayer in alone but you have to follow Iman instead of yourself.Imam will say `Allah o Akber` multiple time and you have to follow it.

1. First Imam say takbeer(when he says `Allah o Akber`) like in prayer alone you say takbeer raising you hand to your ear(but you have to do it after Imam cause you are follow it).
2. Then it the same farz salat when he say `Allah o Akber` again you bow and put your hand to knees.
3. when he will say `Allah o Akber` you stand straight.
4. he will say `Allah o Akber` again you will go to sajdah. Remember you have to perform two sadjah so he will say `Allah o Akber` again you will get up from sajdah and then when he will say `Allah o Akber` again you go into the sajdah again after that he will say `Allah o Akber` you will stand up straight.(your one rakat is over)
5. Now you will follow these same steps again but in after sajdah you will sit and perform you ayat and end with salam.

Now my advice for you is not to get nerves cause no one is looking at you. You are there to perform your prayer:D

Comment: You answered nearly all my questions.Only one left bro(and it is important ) :). How the prayer is done? I know how to pray alone but i don't know how to pray in a group? tell me exactly what changes happens if possible ?

Comment: @user3098 now you can check it i have updated my answer.

Comment: This sounds to me as a hanafi "sequence". As there's no clearly prescribed  sunna before Jumu'a.